# Unable to update .bashrc file from AWS CloudFormation script

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently working on making a cloudformation template that creates a simple EC2 instance using the Amazon AMI. After this instance is created I have a UserData field that will run bash code in the new instance to install Jenkins, Git, Apache Maven, etc and update the PATH variable and ./bashrc file.

I successfully completed most of these requirements, but whenever I try to echo anything into the bashrc file, it seems to not work. I even checked the log file in the EC2 instance that is generated after running the bash code and it has no errors or anything that went wrong.

Here is my cloudformation code in its entirety:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template EC2InstanceWithSecurityGroupSample: Create an Amazon EC2 instance running the Amazon Linux AMI. The AMI is chosen based on the region in which the stack is run. This example creates an EC2 security group for the instance to give you SSH access. **WARNING** This template creates an Amazon EC2 instance. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.",

  "Parameters" : {
    "KeyName": {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    },

    "InstanceType" : {
      "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "t2.small",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "t1.micro", "t2.nano", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium", "t2.large", "m1.small", "m1.medium", "m1.large", "m1.xlarge", "m2.xlarge", "m2.2xlarge", "m2.4xlarge", "m3.medium", "m3.large", "m3.xlarge", "m3.2xlarge", "m4.large", "m4.xlarge", "m4.2xlarge", "m4.4xlarge", "m4.10xlarge", "c1.medium", "c1.xlarge", "c3.large", "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge", "c3.8xlarge", "c4.large", "c4.xlarge", "c4.2xlarge", "c4.4xlarge", "c4.8xlarge", "g2.2xlarge", "g2.8xlarge", "r3.large", "r3.xlarge", "r3.2xlarge", "r3.4xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "i2.xlarge", "i2.2xlarge", "i2.4xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "d2.xlarge", "d2.2xlarge", "d2.4xlarge", "d2.8xlarge", "hi1.4xlarge", "hs1.8xlarge", "cr1.8xlarge", "cc2.8xlarge", "cg1.4xlarge"]
,
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },

    "SSHLocation" : {
      "Description" : "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
   }
  },

  "Mappings" : {
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "t2.nano"     : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.10xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "g2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVMG2"  },
      "g2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVMG2"  },
      "r3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hi1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hs1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cr1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  }
    },

    "AWSInstanceType2NATArch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "t2.nano"     : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.10xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "g2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVMG2"  },
      "g2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVMG2"  },
      "r3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "hi1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "hs1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "cr1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  }
    }
,
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
      "us-east-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-8ff710e2", "HVM64" : "ami-f5f41398", "HVMG2" : "ami-4afd1d27"},
      "us-west-2"        : {"PV64" : "ami-eff1028f", "HVM64" : "ami-d0f506b0", "HVMG2" : "ami-ee897b8e"},
      "us-west-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-ac85fbcc", "HVM64" : "ami-6e84fa0e", "HVMG2" : "ami-69106909"},
      "eu-west-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-23ab2250", "HVM64" : "ami-b0ac25c3", "HVMG2" : "ami-936de5e0"},
      "eu-central-1"     : {"PV64" : "ami-27c12348", "HVM64" : "ami-d3c022bc", "HVMG2" : "ami-8e7092e1"},
      "ap-northeast-1"   : {"PV64" : "ami-26160d48", "HVM64" : "ami-29160d47", "HVMG2" : "ami-91809aff"},
      "ap-northeast-2"   : {"PV64" : "NOT_SUPPORTED", "HVM64" : "ami-cf32faa1", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ap-southeast-1"   : {"PV64" : "ami-f3dd0a90", "HVM64" : "ami-1ddc0b7e", "HVMG2" : "ami-3c30e75f"},
      "ap-southeast-2"   : {"PV64" : "ami-8f94b9ec", "HVM64" : "ami-0c95b86f", "HVMG2" : "ami-543d1137"},
      "sa-east-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-e188018d", "HVM64" : "ami-fb890097", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "cn-north-1"       : {"PV64" : "ami-77a46e1a", "HVM64" : "ami-05a66c68", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"}
    }

  },

  "Resources" : {
    "EC2Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                          { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
             "#!/bin/bash\n",
             "#Automation script to set-up Continuous Integration environment in AWS\n",
             "#Installs Jenkins, Git, JDK, Grails, Apache Maven, and SonarQube Scanner\n",
             "#Connects to AWS Artifactory repo to download software\n",
             "#Update these fields with the version numbers you would like for each software installation\n",
             "jenkinsVersion='2.9'\n",
             "gitVersion='2.7.4'\n",
             "jdkVersion='8'\n",
             "jdkUpdate='91'\n",
             "grailsVersion='3.1.8'\n",
             "mavenVersion='3.3.9'\n",
             "sonarqubeVersion='2.6.1'\n",

             "#Install Jenkins\n",
             "sudo wget http://172.31.62.161:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/jenkins-$jenkinsVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo unzip jenkins-$jenkinsVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo rm jenkins-$jenkinsVersion.zip\n",
             "cd jenkins-$jenkinsVersion\n",
             "sudo mv jenkins.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo\n",
             "sudo rpm --import jenkins.io.key\n",
             "sudo yum install jenkins -y\n",
             "sudo rm jenkins.io.key \n",
             "cd\n",

             "#Install Git\n",
             "sudo wget http://172.31.62.161:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/git-$gitVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo unzip git-$gitVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo rm git-$gitVersion.zip\n",
             "cd git-$gitVersion\n",
             "sudo rpm -Uvh *rpm\n",
             "sudo rm -rf git-$gitVersion\n",
             "cd\n",

             "cd /opt #Change directory to /opt\n",

             "#Install Oracle JDK\n",
             "sudo wget http://172.31.62.161:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/jdk-$jdkVersion'u'$jdkUpdate-linux-x64.tar.gz\n",
             "sudo tar xzf jdk-$jdkVersion'u'$jdkUpdate-linux-x64.tar.gz\n",
             "sudo rm jdk-$jdkVersion'u'$jdkUpdate-linux-x64.tar.gz\n",
             "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.'$jdkVersion'.0_'$jdkUpdate >> ~/.bashrc\n",
             "echo 'export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc\n",

             "#Install Grails\n",
             "sudo wget http://172.31.62.161:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/grails-$grailsVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo unzip grails-$grailsVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo rm grails-$grailsVersion.zip\n",
             "echo 'export GRAILS_HOME=/opt/grails-'$grailsVersion >> ~/.bashrc\n",
             "echo 'export PATH=$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc\n", 

             "#Install Apache Maven\n",
             "sudo wget http://172.31.62.161:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/apache-maven-$mavenVersion-bin.tar.gz\n",
             "sudo tar xzf apache-maven-$mavenVersion-bin.tar.gz\n",
             "sudo rm apache-maven-$mavenVersion-bin.tar.gz\n",
             "echo 'export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-'$mavenVersion >> ~/.bashrc\n",
             "echo 'export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc\n",

             "#Install SonarQube Scanner\n",
             "sudo wget http://172.31.62.161:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/sonar-scanner-$sonarqubeVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo unzip sonar-scanner-$sonarqubeVersion.zip\n",
             "sudo rm sonar-scanner-$sonarqubeVersion.zip\n",
             "echo 'export SONAR_SCANNER_HOME=/opt/sonar-scanner-'$sonarqubeVersion >> ~/.bashrc\n",
             "echo 'export PATH=$SONAR_SCANNER_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc\n"
             ]]}}
      }
    },

    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access via port 22",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "22",
          "ToPort" : "22",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        } ]
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    "InstanceId" : {
      "Description" : "InstanceId of the newly created EC2 instance",
      "Value" : { "Ref" : "EC2Instance" }
    },
    "AZ" : {
      "Description" : "Availability Zone of the newly created EC2 instance",
      "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance", "AvailabilityZone" ] }
    },
    "PublicDNS" : {
      "Description" : "Public DNSName of the newly created EC2 instance",
      "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance", "PublicDnsName" ] }
    },
    "PublicIP" : {
      "Description" : "Public IP address of the newly created EC2 instance",
      "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance", "PublicIp" ] }
    }
  }
}
```

I even tested just using the echo command normally and it works fine. If I try to echo anything into the bashrc file it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I'd try.

First, your script runs as root, so the sudo commands aren't needed.  That shouldn't affect anything, but you should know what user your script is running under.

Second, but related to the first, are you looking for changes in /root/.bashrc or /home/ec2-user/.bashrc?  If the latter, specify the full path.

Comment: I will try this out and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Chris I just confirmed that this method worked. Thanks so much. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are a life saver. When I SSH the EC2 instance and run the command, the output is appended to /home/ubuntu/.bashrc script. When it runs inside CloudFormation, the output is appended to /root/.bashrc script. I figured out that CloudFormation runs the terminal commands as the root user.